# How to open a url link as a popup screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an url, lets say `www.myurl.com/mywebpage` and when I type this url in browser it opens my page and everything works fine.

Now my requirement is that when I type this url in browser,the webpage should open like a pop up.
As there is no button click or such event, I cannot write `window.open` javascript function to open this as pop up.

Is there any other way(jquery) or how we can use window.open function to show my page as popup when the url is hit in the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you were designing a car, would you swap the accelerator and brake pedals? Deliberately attempting to override the standard & expected behaviour of a website is a terrible, terrible, terrible usability mistake. People will expect to open your website like every other website. Don't try and make it do something different.

Comment: i agree.But we can make user feel that it opens as pop up..If there is nothing different in making then nothing new comes.

Comment: In general I agree with Varga but innovation is, by definition, changing the "standard & expected behavior" of something, and not all innovation is bad.  Use popups wisely and thoughtfully.Most of all don't make the user experience dependent on them.

Answer (score 7):

just using window.open(with out any function) in html solved my problem.

in page1.html i wrote the following script

```
<script>
window.open("http://google.com", "myWindow", 'width=800,height=600');
window.close();
</script>
```

When i type page1.html in browser address,it opens google page as a popup.

Thanks everyone for your efforts in trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such function without user interaction

---

You could create a `dialog()` widget with jQuery, however.

See: https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-popup-window/

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/yusenu/2/](http://jsbin.com/yusenu/2/watch?html,output)

Answer (score -1):

try this code:   (popupex.html will replace with your page url)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>click demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')"
        >Link to popup</a>
<script>
function popitup(url) {
        newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have so much commented out?

Comment: `<a href="popupex.html" target="_blank" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')"
        >Link to popup</a>` usually does the job, but in browsers that have tabs, it may open as a new tab!

Comment: @Santosh popupex.html is just for example just change it with your link which you want to open in popup window. like " sitenameORurl.com/mypage.html "